# Error for pipe: int not a function

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm using this code to try to implement my own pipe in a simple shell. However, it won't compile because it's telling me fd is not a function. Every other place I've seen this implemented has fd as the parameter for pipe() in the exact same way. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

```
int startProcess (StringArray sa)
{
  int pid; 
  int status;
  int fd1;
  int fd2; 
  int current_in;
  int current_out;
  int fd0;
  int fd00;
  int in = 0;
  int out = 0; 
  char input[64]="";
  char output[64]="";
  char cmd1[64] ="";
  char cmd2[64] ="";
  int pipe = 0; 
  int fd[2]; 

  switch( pid = fork()){
 case -1://This is an error 
   perror("Failure of child.");
   return 1;
 case 0: // This is the child
   // Redirection

   /* finds where '<' or '>' or '|' occurs and make that sa[i] = NULL ,
      to ensure that command wont' read that*/

    for(int i=0;sa[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(sa[i],"<")==0)
        {        
            sa[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(input,sa[i+1]);
            in=2;           
        }               

        if(strcmp(sa[i],">")==0)
        {      
            sa[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(output,sa[i+1]);
            out=2;
        }
        if(strcmp(sa[i],"|")==0)
        {
            sa[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(cmd1,sa[i-1]);
            strcpy(cmd2,sa[i+1]);
            pipe=2; 
        }

    }

    //if '<' char was found in string inputted by user
   (erased for brevity) 


    //if '>' char was found in string inputted by user 
    (erased for brevity) 

     //if '|' char was found in string inputted by user
    if(pipe)
    {
        pipe(fd); 
        if (!fork)
        {
            close(1);
            dup(fd[1]); 
            close(fd[0]);
            int error; 
            error = 0; 
            if (fork() == 0){
                error = execvp(cmd1, sa); 

            } if (error == -1) {
                printf("ERROR: unknown command (%s)\n)", cmd1); 
                exit(0); 
            } else {
                waitpid(0,NULL,0); 
            }
        }
    } else {
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(cmd2, sa); 
    }

          execvp(sa[0], sa);
          perror("execvp");
          _exit(1);


    printf("Could not execute '%s'\n", sa[0]);
  default:// This is the parent 
   wait(&status);
   return (status == 0) ? 0: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: Your `pipe` is both an `int` and function. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

First you have

```
int pipe = 0;
```

Then you also have

```
pipe(fd);
```

Both can't be correct.

I suggest you rename the variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is so helpful having someone else look over my code.